# Using java.util.Timer

Tags: java, android, timer

Trying to make a timer call a method every second. I can't figure out why this code is not working. Code was taken from my activity_main.xml and MainActivity.java

activity_main:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btnStartStop"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/clockDisplay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/clockDisplay"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:textOff="Start"
    android:textOn="Stop"
    android:onClick="toggleStartStop" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public void toggleStartStop(View view){
        if(((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()){
            Timer timer = new Timer("timer", true);
            TimerTask task = new startTask();
            timer.schedule(task, new Date(), 1000);
        }else{
            stopTimer();
        }
    }

class startTask extends TimerTask 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("inc secs var");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? The thread is not being started ? Provide some more details.

Comment: Try and use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead

Comment: I'll check that out. In the meantime... I run the app, click the button, nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, use a breakpoint or a `Log.d()` call to see if the timer-setup code is running. It's also better to use `Log.d()` than `println()` in general.

On Android, it's better to [send a message to a](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) `Handler` than use a Java Timer. The OS can manage this better, e.g. during the Activity lifecycle.

```
class UpdateHandler extends Handler {
    private static final int MSG_UPDATE = 1;
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000; // msec

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_UPDATE:
                // do stuff...
                scheduleNextUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    void scheduleNextUpdate() {
        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks almost like an interrupt in C. I'll try that soon

Comment: Log.d actually worked. I'm working on using the handler

Comment: handlers were not the answer as I was trying to update the UI every second. (Can't update the UI from a different thread).

Comment: To be able to update the UI, call the no-arg Handler() constructor from the UI thread. You can send it Messages from any thread, if needed. This works, at least until the Activity stops.

Comment: yes you're right... was just messing around with it and fixed it! I am just a confused beginner